# C++ POCO NET delete packet before send

Tags: c++, tcp, poco, packet

I got one problem, when i send big packet (5 000 bytes), packet is deleted before send, so server crashes.

Is there way to delete packet when it's sended ?

Without delete [] server works propertly.

Here is code :

```
            case 675:
                char * datax;
                datax = new char [5824]();
                datax[0] = 0xc0;
                datax[1] = 0x16;
                datax[4] = 4;
                datax[6] = 1;
                datax[8] = 1;
                datax[10] = 1;
                datax[12] = 0xb1;
                datax[13] = 0x09;
                datax[20] = 1;
                datax[24] = 0x16;
                datax[28] = 0x05;
                datax[29] = 0x09;
                datax[30] = 0x0e;
                datax[5801] = 0xc0;//coords
                datax[5802] = 0xb7;
                datax[5803] = 0xc4;
                datax[5805] = 0xe0;
                datax[5806] = 0x21;
                datax[5807] = 0x45;//end
                datax[5808] = 0x0c;
                datax[5813] = 0x9d;
                datax[5814] = 0x0f;
                datax[5815] = 0xbf;
                datax[5822] = 0x52;
                datax[5823] = 0x2a;
                _socket.sendBytes(datax, 5824);
                delete [] datax; //here crash
                break;
```

Comment: Not suggesting this is the right solution (it ISN'T), but if you add a 0.5 second "sleep" after `sendBytes`, before `delete`, does that "fix" the problem? To me, this seems strange, because a sane implementation of network drivers would make a copy of the whole buffer before returning to the client code.

Comment: sleeping thread will be bad option, but my thread poll has only 8 threads

Comment: The purpose of sleeping is not to FIX the problem (I tried to make that clear in the previous post!), but to identify if the `delete` immediately after send is the problem or not. To me, it doesn't make sense. Alternatively, you could just not delete the block at all - assuming your machine has a few gigabytes of RAM, it will take quite some time to send enough packets to use up all the memory - 4000 packets is just over 20MB, so in 2GB you'd get some 400000 packets... If it all goes well, then you know it's the `delete` that causes the problem. If not, then the problem is not the `delete`...

Comment: Yes, but as long as you know that it's leaking, and that you are doing it on purpose for debugging, it's not an issue - just remember to put the delete back in once you have debugged it. Again, the purpose is not to fix your bug, but to identify what is causing the bug - if it goes away by removing `delete`, then that's a key to the problem. If you still have a problem after removing `delete`, then it's something else causing the problem!

Comment: I think strcpy from pointer to char array and delete pointer will be enough.

Comment: Yes, but that will HIDE the problem if there is one! You don't want to HIDE it, you want to identify it!

Comment: Will there help edition of POCO sendBytes function to remove buffer ?

Comment: Not sure that what question means...

Comment: Edit POCO sendBytes function to delete char pointer after send.

Comment: My point is that what you describe doesn't make sense - the call should not return until the buffer is safely in the somewhere it's not going to matter what you do with the buffer, because you may well want to either free the memory, or you want to overwrite the content with something new - and I couldn't find any "wait for send to complete". So I'm trying to find a way to make it obvious that it's NOT `delete` that causes the problems you are seeing. This is how `fwrite`, `fstream::write`, the `write` system call, etc works.

Comment: Solved, sending is set default to non-blocking, so it return when unfinished, set blocking flag solve this problem.

Comment: Ah, that would do that...